# Error: cardElevation and cardUseCompatPadding not found

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-studio-3.0

**After updating Android Studio `2.3.3` to `3.0`,  CardView  in XML can't find `cardElevation` and `cardUseCompactPadding`**. **My current Support Library version `26.1.0`**

Here is xml code :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
android:id="@+id/cardS"
app:cardElevation="5dp">
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/search_fragment_searchViewQuery"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme"
    app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Log Error :

```
Error:error: attribute 'com.y34h1a.project:cardElevation' not found.
Error:error: attribute 'com.y34h1a.project:cardUseCompatPadding' not found.
Error:attribute 'com.y34h1a.project:cardElevation' not found.
Error:attribute 'com.y34h1a.project:cardUseCompatPadding' not found.
```

There are other errors :

```
Error:failed linking file resources.  
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for 
details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for 
details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs 
for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt
```

**Clean and Rebuild project not solving this problem.**

Comment: It seems you used the library  _com.y34h1a.project_ . So correct the library's gradle too for 3.0

Comment: this is my project package name. not library.

Comment: then just check your _values/attr.xml_ file. or just clear your project and rebuild.

Comment: And always remember (my suggestion/experience) don't try to update your android studio for your existing projects. It may lead to completely mess sometimes. If you want to make new projects on new studio version just download and use them as portable.(I use like this) _Don't update current running studio_

Comment: after removing cardElevation and cardUseCompact project working fine

Comment: Check this guide: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#aapt2

Answer (score 7):

Even I came across the same issue after updating Android Studio from 2.3.3 to 3.0

I did the following which helped me overcome the problem - 

1. Update compileSdkVersion to 26

```
compileSdkVersion 26
```

2. Update targetSdkVersion to 26

```
targetSdkVersion 26
```

3. Update Cardview Support Library to 26.1.0

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

I just add `'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'` to my project dependencies then it's worked!